# What is the proper way to use includes (Rails 4, ActiveRecord, PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following Models:

**Moon -> Planet -> Star -> Galaxy -> Universe**

Moon `belongs_to` Planet, Planet `belongs_to` Star and so on:

---

```
class Moon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :planet, inverse_of: :moons

  has_one :star, through: :planet
  has_one :galaxy, through: :star
  has_one :universe, through: :galaxy
end
```

---

```
class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :star, inverse_of: :planets
    has_many :moons, inverse_of: :planet, dependent: :destroy
end
```

---

### The Problem

I'm trying to get Rails to load a hierarchy of these objects to memory. I'm trying to achieve 2 things:

1. Load everything using one efficient query
2. Be able to use calls such as `moon.galaxy` and not `moon.planet.star.galaxy` without additional calls to the database.

I tried two approaches. The first (`m1`) is calling `includes` on `Moon` with all the relations flatten. This results in a very inefficient query but I can call `m1.galaxy`. The second (`m2`) is calling `includes` with the hierarchy of relations. This results in an efficient query, but I can call `m2.galaxy` without going to the database.

What is the proper way to do that?

---

### Example

**m1 - inefficient query, m2 - efficient query**

```
irb(main):152:0* m1 = Moon.includes(:planet, :star, :galaxy).where(galaxies: {name: 'The Milky Way'}).first
  SQL (1.9ms)  SELECT  "moons"."id" AS t0_r0, "moons"."name" AS t0_r1, "moons"."planet_id" AS t0_r2, "moons"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "moons"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "planets"."id" AS t1_r0, "planets"."name" AS t1_r1, "planets"."star_id" AS t1_r2, "planets"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "planets"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "stars"."id" AS t2_r0, "stars"."name" AS t2_r1, "stars"."galaxy_id" AS t2_r2, "stars"."created_at" AS t2_r3, "stars"."updated_at" AS t2_r4, "galaxies"."id" AS t3_r0, "galaxies"."name" AS t3_r1, "galaxies"."universe_id" AS t3_r2, "galaxies"."created_at" AS t3_r3, "galaxies"."updated_at" AS t3_r4 FROM "moons" LEFT OUTER JOIN "planets" ON "planets"."id" = "moons"."planet_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "planets" "planets_moons_join" ON "planets_moons_join"."id" = "moons"."planet_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stars" ON "stars"."id" = "planets_moons_join"."star_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "planets" "planets_moons_join_2" ON "planets_moons_join_2"."id" = "moons"."planet_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stars" "stars_moons_join" ON "stars_moons_join"."id" = "planets_moons_join_2"."star_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "galaxies" ON "galaxies"."id" = "stars_moons_join"."galaxy_id" WHERE "galaxies"."name" = $1  ORDER BY "moons"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["name", "The Milky Way"]]
=> #<Moon id: 1, name: "The Moon", planet_id: 1, created_at: "2015-10-28 10:02:04", updated_at: "2015-10-28 10:02:04">

irb(main):153:0> m2 = Moon.includes(planet: {star: :galaxy}).where(galaxies: {name: 'The Milky Way'}).first
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT  "moons"."id" AS t0_r0, "moons"."name" AS t0_r1, "moons"."planet_id" AS t0_r2, "moons"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "moons"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "planets"."id" AS t1_r0, "planets"."name" AS t1_r1, "planets"."star_id" AS t1_r2, "planets"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "planets"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "stars"."id" AS t2_r0, "stars"."name" AS t2_r1, "stars"."galaxy_id" AS t2_r2, "stars"."created_at" AS t2_r3, "stars"."updated_at" AS t2_r4, "galaxies"."id" AS t3_r0, "galaxies"."name" AS t3_r1, "galaxies"."universe_id" AS t3_r2, "galaxies"."created_at" AS t3_r3, "galaxies"."updated_at" AS t3_r4 FROM "moons" LEFT OUTER JOIN "planets" ON "planets"."id" = "moons"."planet_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stars" ON "stars"."id" = "planets"."star_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "galaxies" ON "galaxies"."id" = "stars"."galaxy_id" WHERE "galaxies"."name" = $1  ORDER BY "moons"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["name", "The Milky Way"]]
=> #<Moon id: 1, name: "The Moon", planet_id: 1, created_at: "2015-10-28 10:02:04", updated_at: "2015-10-28 10:02:04">
```

**m1 - I can call moon.galaxy.name in memory, m2 - moon.galaxy.name calls DB**

```
irb(main):154:0> m1.galaxy.name
=> "The Milky Way"

irb(main):155:0> m2.galaxy.name
  Galaxy Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "galaxies".* FROM "galaxies" INNER JOIN "stars" ON "galaxies"."id" = "stars"."galaxy_id" INNER JOIN "planets" ON "stars"."id" = "planets"."star_id" WHERE "planets"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> "The Milky Way"
```

**m1 - moon.planet.star.galaxy.name calls DB, m2 - I can call moon.planet.star.galaxy.name in memory**

```
irb(main):156:0> m1.planet.star.galaxy.name
  Star Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  "stars".* FROM "stars" WHERE "stars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Galaxy Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "galaxies".* FROM "galaxies" WHERE "galaxies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> "The Milky Way"

irb(main):157:0> m2.planet.star.galaxy.name
=> "The Milky Way"
```

---

### A Diff of the Queries

[image: Inefficient vs. Efficient]

Comment: with respect to the eager loading, consider reading up on the different ways to do so in Rails. There are many articles (some more up-to-date than others) which go in detail and you should be able to find some information there to help, e.g., http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think your second way (m2) is correct. Bay also consider `eager_load` because `includes` may trigger several SQL queries instead of one for each association (planet, start etc).

I think your problem in these incorrect associations `star`, `galaxy` and `universe`.

```
class Moon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :planet, inverse_of: :moons

  has_one :star, through: :planet
  has_one :galaxy, through: :star
  has_one :universe, through: :galaxy
end
```

Just remove them and try again.

Please notice you can't use `has_one` such way ([example in documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not convinced that using `has_one through:` with `belongs_to` is incorrect. See here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one
Also, if I remove them then I'm unable to write `moon.galaxy`, which is part of what I was trying to do in the first place.

Comment: 1) using `has_one` assosiation in Moon model is incorrect. You can find this statement "This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key." when follow your link :).

Comment: 2) if you want to access `galaxy` (for example) from the `moon` is direct access through `belongs_to` associations an option? I mean following: in moon model  `delegate :star, to: :planet, prefix: false; delegate :galaxy, :to :star, prefix: false`.

Comment: 1) From the doc: "You can only use a :through query through a **has_one or belongs_to** association on the join model"

2) Good point. Any idea how I can do this also when the relation is has_many (e.g I'd like to be able to write galaxy.moons)

Comment: 1) FYI check documentation for the belongs_to association (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to), the :through is't listed. Again you can't use has_one association in the Moon model. 2) it's easy to access child models (moons) from the parent (planet, galaxy etc) - just use `has_many and has_many :through` in the Planet and galaxy models